# Why git, curl and such tools can't use system network proxy?

Tags: curl, git, macos

My OS: MacOSX

git, curl can use `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` environment variables. So that they can use them at runtime and access the target server via my proxy server.

Why git, curl and such tools can't use system WIFI network proxy settings?

Didn't they all end up sending requests through my wifi network?

Debugging Details:

WIFI HTTP proxy setting:

[image]

```bsh
⚡  curl google.com    
curl: (7) Failed to connect to google.com port 80: Operation timed out
```

---

Clear WIFI HTTP proxy setting:

[image]

Set `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `all_proxy` environment variables.

```bsh
⚡  export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890 http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890 all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7890
⚡  echo $http_proxyhttp://127.0.0.1:7890
http://127.0.0.1:7890
⚡  curl google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

curl can access the `google.com` site.

Comment: That's strange… are you sure they don't ? have you tried curling a website that gives you your ip address to check?

Comment: @Nephanth I added my debugging details.

Comment: Honestly, I think you could try asking on askdifferent (apple-focused stackexchange) because this looks like a specificity of the mac settings provider :/

Answer (score 3):

For command line tools like `curl` etc. "system proxy settings" is exactly what you have set in your second example - that is, the variables `$http_proxy` etc. Does the GUI tool you use for setting "system proxy settings" set these variables for terminal sessions? If not, then you have the answer why the settings are not used. Simply your GUI proxy setting application is incompatible with command line tools.

`$http_proxy` etc. environment variables are *nix command-line standard. Whoever writes a GUI application to set proxy and wants that setting to be applicable to command-line tools, needs to conform to that standard. Not the other way around, because there are myriads of possible ways how the graphical DEs would store proxy information and command line tools can't know all of them (also there's no sense in it, because by definition command line tools can run - and usually are run - without any graphical DE running). Think that you have the same `curl` code being run under GNOME, KDE, XFCE, multitude of other Linux DEs, Windows native DE, MacOS native DE or in simple text-mode ssh session without any DE...

Proxy setting in any GUI tool **should** result in subsequent setting of `$http_proxy` etc. variables for terminal sessions. If not, then the GUI tool is bad.

Answer (score 2):

The environment variables you're using here are the standard Unix way to express proxy settings in normal Unix tools, including command-line tools.  This design has a couple of benefits:

- It allows you to customize per-program which proxy to use or whether to use a proxy at all.
- It allows a great deal of specificity over proxy settings, including by protocol.
- It works across all Unix systems in a portable way.  Reading settings from macOS specifically would likely require portable programs to link in additional code specific to macOS, probably code written in Objective C.

It is often tempting to think, "Why couldn't vendors just ship a portable library for accessing proxy settings?" but unfortunately nobody has done that and different environments (GNOME, KDE, MATE, macOS) do things completely differently.  Apple specifically also frequently avoids doing things similarly to other Unix systems (e.g., Metal instead of OpenGL and Vulkan; Mach-O instead of ELF), so even if other Unix systems proposed standard tooling, it is unlikely that Apple would ship such a library natively.